# Looping Through XML Subnodes of an XmlDocument

Tags: c#, xml, wpf

I'm writing a WPF application in C# that needs to display data from an XML document. Here is the XML document:

```html
<Schedules>
  <Schedule>
    <Course>
      <ID>CIT160</ID>
      <Section>01</Section>
      <Name>Introduction to Programming</Name>
      <Days>TuTh</Days>
      <STime>09:30</STime>
      <ETime>11:00</ETime>
      <Location>ATHS/E246</Location>
      <Teacher>KREPSHAW, R</Teacher>
    </Course>
    <Course>
      <ID>CIT180</ID>
      <Section>01</Section>
      <Name>Introduction to Database</Name>
      <Days>MW</Days>
      <STime>12:30</STime>
      <ETime>14:00</ETime>
      <Location>ATHS/E235</Location>
      <Teacher>SINGH, M</Teacher>
    </Course>
  </Schedule>
  <Schedule>
    <Course>
      <ID>CIT160</ID>
      <Section>01</Section>
      <Name>Introduction to Programming</Name>
      <Days>TuTh</Days>
      <STime>09:30</STime>
      <ETime>11:00</ETime>
      <Location>ATHS/E246</Location>
      <Teacher>KREPSHAW, R</Teacher>
    </Course>
    <Course>
      <ID>CIT180</ID>
      <Section>25</Section>
      <Name>Introduction to Database</Name>
      <Days>MW</Days>
      <STime>17:00</STime>
      <ETime>18:30</ETime>
      <Location>ATHS/E235</Location>
      <Teacher>SINGH, M</Teacher>
    </Course>
  </Schedule>
</Schedules>
```

I need to output the following:

> Schedule 1
>
> CIT160 01 Introdc... TuTh 09:30 11:00 ATHS/E246 KREPSHAW, R
>
> CIT180 01 Inroduc... MW 12:30 14:00 ATHS/E235 SINGH, M
>
> Schedule 2
>
> CIT160 01 Introdc... TuTH 09:30 11:00 ATHS/E246 KREPSHAW, R
>
> CIT180 25 Introdc... MW 17:00 18:30 ATHS/E235 SINGH, M

How would I iterate through the XML document?

This is what I have so far, but it's not working right.  Please help.

```
private void LoopSchedule()
{
    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDoc.Load("schedule.xml");

    XmlElement root = xmlDoc.DocumentElement;
    XmlElement subRoot = (XmlElement)root.FirstChild;
    XmlNodeList children = subRoot.ChildNodes;     
    
    for(int i = 0; i < children.Count; i++)
    {
        XmlElement courseRoot = (XmlElement)children[i].FirstChild;
        XmlNodeList child = courseRoot.ChildNodes;

        for(int j = 0; j < child.Count; j++)
        {
            StackPanel addPanel = new StackPanel();
            Label lblChild = new Label();
            lblChild.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
            lblChild.Content = child[j].Name;

            addPanel.Children.Add(lblChild);
            stkPan_display.Children.Add(addPanel);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A few points here:

1. You need three loops here, not two.  One for the schedules, one for the courses in each schedule, and one for the data elements in each course.
2. You'll need to create a stack panel and label for the schedule number if you want that in the output.  You don't have such in your code that I see.
3. When creating the stack panel for the course row, you should create it outside the loop for the course children, then add each label to it inside the loop.  You only want one StackPanel per course, not one for each child.
4. You'll need to set the StackPanel orientation to Horizontal for the rows; the default is Vertical.  Also, only set the brush color to white if you've set the background to a dark color, otherwise you won't be able to see it.  The default background is white.

Try this code instead:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load("schedule.xml");

XmlElement root = xmlDoc.DocumentElement;  // Schedules

int scheduleNumber = 0;
foreach (XmlElement schedule in root.ChildNodes)
{
    scheduleNumber++;
    StackPanel schedulePanel = new StackPanel { Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal };
    Label scheduleLabel = new Label { Content = "Schedule " + scheduleNumber.ToString() };
    schedulePanel.Children.Add(scheduleLabel);
    stkPan_display.Children.Add(schedulePanel);

    foreach (XmlElement course in schedule.ChildNodes)
    {
        StackPanel addPanel = new StackPanel { Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal };

        // all child elements of the Course element
        foreach (XmlElement child in course.ChildNodes)
        {
            Label lblChild = new Label();
            lblChild.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
            lblChild.Content = child.InnerText;
            addPanel.Children.Add(lblChild);
        }

        stkPan_display.Children.Add(addPanel);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using xml linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            var schedules = doc.Descendants("Schedule").Select(x => new {
                courses = x.Elements("Course").Select(y => new {
                    id = (string)y.Element("ID"),
                    section = (string)y.Element("Section"),
                    name = (string)y.Element("Name"),
                    days = (string)y.Element("Days"),
                    stime = ((DateTime)y.Element("STime")).TimeOfDay,
                    etime = ((DateTime)y.Element("ETime")).TimeOfDay,
                    location = (string)y.Element("Location"),
                    teacher = (string)y.Element("Teacher")
                }).ToList()
            }).ToList();

        }
    }
}
```